# How to Change/Remove UEFI Hard Disk Password

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, passwords, uefi

I am using an ASUS laptop running Windows 8 and have forgot a UEFI password. The password isn't essential to startup, for I have a user password and a master password. I know the user one, but I've forgotten the master password. The consuquence is I am unable to access any of the 'useful' settings in UEFI firmware (I can't change anything except the date, time, and my user password: the one I know). Since I am trying to disable secure boot for dual booting Ubuntu, this is very fustrating. If you need any additional info, comment.

Thanks in advance.

PS. Both of the passwords (user and master) are hard disk (HDD) passwords.

Comment: I personally would contact ASUS support asking if there is a way to reset the password.

Comment: That would be a last resort. I hope something will pop up here first.